# What's the name of this kind of puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-identification, lights-out

[Link](http://youtu.be/1MzM8WYbSnU) to a video of a the puzzle

What is this puzzle called, and if possible, what is the logic behind it?

Clicking a square inverts the state of the square and the ones directly adjacent to it, and the goal is to get all the squares in a 'On' state.

Comment: My youtube channel is hosting the video, but I've changed never the less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found The Answer. Its called a `lights out puzzle`

[image]

Comment: We even have the [tag:lights-out] tag for this kind of puzzle, which I've just added to the question.

Comment: doesn't seem like that tag is on any questions related to the actual puzzle

Comment: Or it's called "linear algebra over $\Bbb F_2$".

Answer (score 2):

It's called a tile flipping puzzle. 
Each side of a tile is of one of two colors. The goal is to flip tiles until they're all of the same color.
Rules for flipping tiles vary from game to game. Here, it's the selected tile and its neighbors, but it can also be the selected tile and all the other tiles in its row and in its column.